# Octave: How do I convert urlread output to a struct

Tags: api, struct, octave, urlread

I’m running Octave 5.1.0

In Matlab you can use webread to get a struct from a web page, like this:

```
data=webread(urlString);
```

data is then a struct ready to use. (urlString specifies that the format should be json, but I can also get the data in xml format from this web page).

Can I achieve this in Octave? (I can’t use Matlab for this project).

I tried using

```
data=urlread(urlString);
```

data is then in string format. I could use regexp to extract the information I need, but I’m hoping there is an easier way.

I’ll be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Octave does not support JSON reading and writing (yet), but there are a few packages that do so. Try one of them.

- https://github.com/apjanke/octave-jsonstuff
- https://github.com/Andy1978/octave-rapidjson
- https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab